# Build x86 apk with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator, ionic2

Is it possible to build x86 apks with Ionic? When I try to install the apk that Ionic created on an x86 emulator, I get the error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]`. I can run the apk on an arm-based emulator, but it is soooooooo slow that it isn't really usable.

Comment: How are you installing the apk on the emulator?

Comment: Tried dragging and dropping the apk into the emulator, also tried downloading the apk from within the emulator and clicking on it.

Comment: Why don't you just use the ionic cli? Do an `ionic add platform android`, `ionic build android`, `ionic emulate android`. And making sure your x86 is the default emulator in android studio that ionic will run on.

Comment: I've definitely tried that, with the same results. The emulator fails to install the apk.

Comment: You can install plugin 'crosswalk browser' to build with output apk for ARM or Intel X86. Cheer!